# A-Z Crossword Puzzle

Tags: visual, crosswords

[image]

Here is a puzzle made by a friend of mine that I’ve been staring at for a while:

The crossword needs to be filled with the 26 letters of the alphabet, each letter can only only be used once and obviously each row or column has to make a real word as it would do in a crossword.

I believe there are two ways to complete the puzzle. Good luck

Comment: There's a lot of guessing and overall unpredictability involved in this. Can we get a hint for some of the numbers?

Comment: @North- agreed. However, part /type of puzzle solving involves brute force/ trial-and-error...which, in a certain limits are amusing.

Comment: Was this inspired by a GCHQ puzzle, by any chance? The very last puzzle (14th one) in [this post](https://www.gchqpuzzlebook.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gchq/pdf/GCHQ_PuzzleBook_TieBreaker.pdf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are much more than 2 solutions. My friend and I came up with this:

> [image: solution]

Comment: +1 Great answer with no proper nouns necessary.

Comment: Nice! 'm positive there are more than one ways of solving this. I have a feeling there are more solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution which can coincide with a valid crossword

> [image]

Possible clues

> **Across** 
>  2. Zen and chi are confused by small shiny disc. 
>  4. A voice finds its ring between 5 and 10. 
>  5. Insect which does itself? 
>  7. A type of do that may interest deer. 
>  8. Iranian rug is uneasy without Al. 
>  **Down** 
>  1. Religious people who can find French woman to make ornaments. 
>  3. The first vessels which play music? 
>  6. Sounds like you will follow behind in Azerbaijan.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't considered using proper nouns such as I-Pods .... lol. I like your clues, btw.

Comment: @North Good point, it would be an additional challenge to do it without using proper nouns. I'm not sure if that is what the author had in mind

Comment: (ROT13) Fubhyqa'g gur jbeq (1, qbja) or WRJRYYREL vafgrnq bs WRJEL?

Comment: @user477343 "Wrjel" vf n abha juvpu ersref gb Wrjf pbyyrpgviryl. V unir abqqrq gb gur jbeq wrjryyrel va gur pelcgvp pyhr (gur Serapu jbzna ersreevat gb gur "ryyr" cneg). Ubcr gung znxrf frafr.